# How to make banners on one line

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-5

I can't make banners on one line. The block does not appear on the same line.

I tried applying justify-content-between align-items-center but nothing happened. I used a percentage, but nothing came out. Maybe I just inserted the styles in the wrong place.

```
<section className='home-wrapper-1 py-5'>
      <div className='container-xxl'>
        <div className='row'>

          <div className='col-6'>
            <div className='main-banner-content p-3 position-relative'>
              <img src={require('../images/banners/MSI_GT77_HX_13V.jpg')}
                alt='главный баннер' className='img-field' />
              <div className='main-banner-content position-absolute'>
                <h4>Восхождение легенды!</h4>
                <h5>MSI GT77 HX 13V</h5>
              </div>
              <div className='main-banner-button-price p-6 position-absolute'>
                <Link href='/' type='button' className='btn btn-outline-secondary'>Купить сейчас!</Link>
                <p className='m-0'>305.999₽</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

            <div className='d-flex flex-wrap 
            justify-content-between align-items-center'>
              <div className='small-banner-content p-3 position-relative'>
                <img src={require('../images/banners/MSI_GT77_HX_13V.jpg')}
                  alt='главный баннер' className='img-field rounded-2' />
                <div className='small-banner-content position-absolute'>
                  <h4>Восхождение легенды!</h4>
                  <h5>MSI GT77 HX 13V</h5>
                </div>
                <div className='small-banner-button-price position-absolute'>
                  <Link href='/' type='button' className='btn btn-outline-secondary'>Купить сейчас!</Link>
                  <p className='m-0'>305.999₽</p>
                </div>
              </div>

          </div>
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

I tried applying justify-content-between align-items-center but nothing happened.

```
.home-wrapper-1 {
    background-color: rgb(235, 235, 235);
}


.img-field {
    height: 300px;
    width: auto;
}

.main-banner-content {
    top: 10%;
    left: 5%
}

.main-banner-content h4 {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 24px;
    color: var(--color-fcf28c);
    margin:  0 0 12px;
    letter-spacing: 0.3px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.main-banner-content h5 {
    font-size: 38px;
    line-height: 64px;
    letter-spacing: -2px;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 0;
    color: black;
    text-transform: none;
}

.main-banner-button-price {
    bottom: 5%;
    left: 5%;
}
.main-banner-button-price a{
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 1px solid var(--color-fcf28c);
    background-color: var(--color-474747);
}
.main-banner-button-price a:hover{
    background-color: var(--color-474747);
    border: 1px solid var(--color-ffe920);
    color: var(--color-ffe920);
}

.main-banner-button-price p{
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
}

/* SMALL */
.small-banner-content {
    top: 10%;
    left: 5%
}

.small-banner-content h4 {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 24px;
    color: var(--color-fcf28c);
    margin:  0 0 12px;
    letter-spacing: 0.3px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.small-banner-content h5 {
    font-size: 38px;
    line-height: 64px;
    letter-spacing: -2px;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 0;
    color: black;
    text-transform: none;
}

.small-banner-button-price {
    bottom: 5%;
    left: 5%;
}
.small-banner-button-price a{
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 600;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border: 1px solid var(--color-fcf28c);
    background-color: var(--color-474747);
}
.small-banner-button-price a:hover{
    background-color: var(--color-474747);
    border: 1px solid var(--color-ffe920);
    color: var(--color-ffe920);
}

.small-banner-button-price p{
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
}
```

It all looks like this:

[image]

I tried to do it in one line, but it didn't work.

```css
.home-wrapper-1 {
  background-color: rgb(235, 235, 235);
}

.img-field {
  height: 300px;
  width: auto;
}

.main-banner-content {
  top: 10%;
  left: 5%
}

.main-banner-content h4 {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: var(--color-fcf28c);
  margin: 0 0 12px;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.main-banner-content h5 {
  font-size: 38px;
  line-height: 64px;
  letter-spacing: -2px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 0;
  color: black;
  text-transform: none;
}

.main-banner-button-price {
  bottom: 5%;
  left: 5%;
}

.main-banner-button-price a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 1px solid var(--color-fcf28c);
  background-color: var(--color-474747);
}

.main-banner-button-price a:hover {
  background-color: var(--color-474747);
  border: 1px solid var(--color-ffe920);
  color: var(--color-ffe920);
}

.main-banner-button-price p {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
}


/* SMALL */

.small-banner-content {
  top: 10%;
  left: 5%
}

.small-banner-content h4 {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: var(--color-fcf28c);
  margin: 0 0 12px;
  letter-spacing: 0.3px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.small-banner-content h5 {
  font-size: 38px;
  line-height: 64px;
  letter-spacing: -2px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 0;
  color: black;
  text-transform: none;
}

.small-banner-button-price {
  bottom: 5%;
  left: 5%;
}

.small-banner-button-price a {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 1px solid var(--color-fcf28c);
  background-color: var(--color-474747);
}

.small-banner-button-price a:hover {
  background-color: var(--color-474747);
  border: 1px solid var(--color-ffe920);
  color: var(--color-ffe920);
}

.small-banner-button-price p {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section class='home-wrapper-1 py-5'>
  <div class='container-xxl'>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-6'>
        <div class='main-banner-content p-3 position-relative'>
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt='главный баннер' class='img-field' />
          <div class='main-banner-content position-absolute'>
            <h4>Восхождение легенды!</h4>
            <h5>MSI GT77 HX 13V</h5>
          </div>
          <div class='main-banner-button-price p-6 position-absolute'>
            <Link href='/' type='button' class='btn btn-outline-secondary'>Купить сейчас!</Link>
            <p class='m-0'>305.999₽</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class='d-flex flex-wrap 
            justify-content-between align-items-center'>
        <div class='small-banner-content p-3 position-relative'>
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt='главный баннер' class='img-field rounded-2' />
          <div class='small-banner-content position-absolute'>
            <h4>Восхождение легенды!</h4>
            <h5>MSI GT77 HX 13V</h5>
          </div>
          <div class='small-banner-button-price position-absolute'>
            <Link href='/' type='button' class='btn btn-outline-secondary'>Купить сейчас!</Link>
            <p class='m-0'>305.999₽</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Kindly put col-6 in  <div className='d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between align-items-center'></div>

Comment: Does the snippet demo above show your problem? Please revise as necessary. This type of question is best presented as HTML, not JSX.

Comment: Build Though, thank you very much, everything was so easy, I'm blind...